# How to disable history popup in iTerm2?

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I am using iTerm 2 for Mac

How can I disable this "history pop up window"?

[image]

Comment: This is cool, now I wanna know to enable it, haha

Comment: haha.. no you wont,... its annoying, because it popsup "randomly". and you have to press esc to disappear. If you wanna have a "cool" history then use that one: "fzf" https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

Comment: @Alexander I found it. Its `ITERM_SHELL_INTEGRATION_INSTALLED=Yes" when this feature is enabled: https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html. called "View command history"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This history popup window is enabled when you have **"iTerm2 Shell Integration"** installed:
https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html

More detailed: it's the "View command history"-feature:

> It can be seen and searched in the toolbelt or quickly accessed in a popup window.

You can either:

- comment `ITERM_SHELL_INTEGRATION_INSTALLED=Yes` in `$HOME/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh`

or

- remove the complete Shell integration by removing `[[ -e "$HOME/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" ]] && source "$HOME/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"`  from your `$HOME/.zshrc`

Answer (score 1):

You can enable/disable the pop-up (in a recent version, anyway) with View > Auto Command Completion.

Comment: thanks, I just forgot where I enabled it, and search a lot inside config...